# Product detail page showing different CSS for different products

Tags: checkout

I have product pages showing different 'Add to basket' divs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAGDB.jpg - This is what Magento thinks I want
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdeAJ.jpg - This is what I actually want

I've compared these 2 products using Catalogue->Manage products but they seem identical via that.

What has caused the above and more importantly, how do I remove the yellow div in the first image?

Comment: check do you have set custom design for that product in product level?

Comment: Seemingly not.

If I go to Catalogue->Manage Products and then 'Update attributes' on a product then 'Is custom product' is set to 'No'

Answer (score 1):

Probably are products of different types. The yellow div appears to be a configurable product and the other a single product.

Make sure they are the same types and have no custom options.